# React native firebase notification shows while the app is running

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I've made an app using react native firebase 5.6.0. I'm getting notifications from firebase and displaying them with this piece of code:

```
 this.notificationListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
    notification.android
      .setChannelId('channel')
      .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
      .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max)

      .android.setColor('#121243');

    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
  });
```

The problem is push notifications showing even when the app is on foreground and running. I want them to only show when the app is on background.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using AppState

```
  this.notificationListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
if (AppState.currentState != 'active') {
    notification.android
      .setChannelId('channel')
      .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
      .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max)

      .android.setColor('#121243');

    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
}
  });
```

So if the app is in active state the notification won't show.